# Preview image from a tableview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager, nsimageview, ikimageview

I have a tableview that contains a directory's files. When I select a row from the table , I want to preview the contents of it ( for example the  contents of an jpeg image or a pdf file), but I can't find a solution . Do you have any suggestion please?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And you want to create a new view, which gives you additional information about the file, yes?

Comment: I have a tableview which contains directory's files. under it and in the same window I want to preview the content of the file when it is selected in the tableview. do you understand me?

Comment: the tableview contains 4 columns ( icon, name , size and date)

Comment: Well, when you click it, you need to determine the type of the item in question, create an according view and add it as an 'overlay' to the tableview, which will be dismissed upon tap or something. At least that's the way I understand it.